# DSV file import to SQL using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a .dsv file and I need to import into sql database. I tried converting into text and csv file format but I am unable to import them properly.
The file is `"|"` delimited and it is unable to discover `"|"`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In SS Data Tools 2012 you may specify delimiter for flat file connection in Flat file connection properties - Columns - Column Delimiter. Is there such options in SSDT 2008?

Comment: @zack are you using the import export wizard in SSMS?  If you are, under columns there is a column delimiter drop down and you can change the delimiter to "Vertical Bar".